# Truncating NSString to fit a particular width

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I've got a variable-width-font NSString that has to fit inside a fixed size UIView. Currently, the string gets truncated and rendered.

I want to obtain the visible substring so I can append an elipsis (…) to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `UILabel`, you can set the `lineBreakMode` to one of

```
UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation
UILineBreakModeTailTruncation
UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation
```

The different positions refer to where the `...` goes.  You want `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode

Comment: Just make your UILabel fits to the size of the UIView.